# Requested Service not found

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, .net-remoting

I have a windows service application which works using remoting. It is used to display baloon tip. However, it sometimes throws this error:

```
Exception :Requested Service not found
Inner Exception : 

Stack Trace :

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryServerFormatterSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Baloontip.clsBaloonTool.Messagebox(String Message)
```

Can any body please help me with this issue.

Comment: Please post the code that is causing this exception to appear.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the error occurs after some time, it is possible that you doesn´t override the `InitializeLifetimeService` method of the base class [MarshalByRefObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx).

By default, if you doesn´t override the method, the remote object is destroyed after some time (I think 5 minutes). If you override the method and return null, the object has an endless life time.

```
public override object InitializeLifetimeService() {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Man you saved me!  I don't know enough about remoting and it would have taken me forever to figure this out without this answer!

Comment: Hi Jehof, you saved me too! I have spent many 5 minutes today for testing the remoting service vanishing problem in my hooking system. Thank you for the great advice!