# Why is this remoting service not found only when running mspec.exe?

Tags: resharper, remoting, mspec

This happens only when running tests with `mspec.exe`. They run fine in ReSharper's test runner. The `Establish` and `Because` statements execute, then the exception below appears right after reaching the first `It` statement.

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException occurred
Message=Requested Service not found
Source=System.Runtime.Remoting
StackTrace:
  Server stack trace: 
     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryServerFormatterSink.ProcessMessage    (IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Machine.Specifications.Runner.ISpecificationRunListener.OnSpecificationStart(SpecificationInfo specification)
   at Machine.Specifications.Runner.Impl.AggregateRunListener.<>c__DisplayClass11.<OnSpecificationStart>b__10(ISpecificationRunListener listener) in c:\OLDMSPEC\machine-machine.specifications-98b543c\Source\Machine.Specifications\Runner\Impl\AggregateRunListener.cs:line 49
```

I tried what was said here but it didn't work: [Spec fails when run by mspec.exe, but passes when run by TD.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326847/spec-fails-when-run-by-mspec-exe-but-passes-when-run-by-td-net/2351703#2351703)

I would like some general ideas, as the code is broken into many classes and there are many steps, so it would be difficult for me to provide sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I've never encountered that Requested Service not found error and I really have no idea what could have caused it. A reproduction would be really great and some info if your code broke on a specific version (and has been working before). There are some fundamental differences between the ReSharper and console runners, namely ReSharper using a custom remoting facility whereas the console runner uses vanilla .NET remoting. I know it might be difficult, but a reproduction that isolates the problem would be great. (I'm currently on vacation and can help from April 20 onwards.)

Answer (score 0):

We have a custom remote runner. The following thread helped me fix the issue. [Requested Service not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651852/requested-service-not-found?rq=1)

Alexander, thanks for your help.